# ArcGIS Online Smart Editor Widget

Tags: arcgis-online

I'm new with ArcGIS Online and I'm trying to create a survey kind of thing using Web AppBuilder and Smart Editor. I have a feature layer (hosted) but in smart editor I can't change the insert object name (shown on the picture with red). It's probably really simple fix but I'm little bit stuck.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can change this text. If your users won't understand 'new feature' the best option may be to go into the general settings for the widget, scroll to the bottom, and in the 'Provide text to display for the editing panel' section add in text explaining what to do. This text will appear at the top of the widget. Alternatively if users change the language settings of their accounts I believe this text will update to their chosen language (have not tested this though, but think that is how it is supposed to work).

Answer (score 0):

The text is not translated choosing different languages.

You can check this to know how:
https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-online-questions/translating-widgets-in-webapp-builder/td-p/706455

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).